# RecyclerView adding Item onclickListener() + timers optimization

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

I want to add an onClickListener to items in my RecyclerView. I added the listener in the Holder class as follows:

```
public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView firstName;
    TextView lastName;

    public Holder (final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        firstName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstName );
        lastName= itemView.findViewById(R.id.lastName);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Do work
             }
        }
    }
```

But, I think this will cause the scrolling of the list to be a little jerky and not perfectly smooth specially on old devices.

**Question 1:**
Is there a better way to do that? Or how can I optimize my code?

**Question 2:**
 I intend to add a dynamically changing variable for each item in the list such as a timer, and I don't want the scrolling to be too slow! How should I update the timers the best way?

Answer (score 1):

Create a member variable for item OnClickListener and set it in Holder's constructor.It will be one listener in your adapter when app is running.

Answer (score 1):

## Jerky Scrolling

Since you are using RecyclerView I don't think that you will face any issue with scrolling because RecyclerView inherently comes with ViewHolder Pattern. (In case of Simple listView you have to make ViewHolder to avoid jerky scrolling)

## Code improvement

Instead of adding a Listener in ViewHolder, make it a Class variable in your RecyclerView Adapter.

There is a standard way to add a Listener in RecyclerView

> Create a listener

```
interface ClickListener{
   
       void click();

}
```

> implement this listener to Your Activity

```
YourActivity implements ClickListener{

}
```

> Typecast this listener in Your Adapter

```
YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.Holder>{

    ClickListener listener; 

    public YourAdapter(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        
        listener = (ClickListener)context;
    }


    public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

         TextView firstName;
         TextView lastName;

          public Holder (final View itemView) {
              super(itemView);
              firstName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstName );
              lastName= itemView.findViewById(R.id.lastName);
    
    }

    // Item Click listener goes here.

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DownLoadViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            // Do something
            listener.click(); 
    
      }

}
```

Just giving you the overview.
You can see [THIS](https://github.com/rohitksingh/OLA_Play_Music_App/blob/master/OlaPlay/app/src/main/java/rohksin/com/olaplay/Adapters/DownloadAdapter.java) for reference.